# Translator in PHP issue

Tags: php, translation

I am using a translator class i found online. It works phenomenally when I use it to directly echo the message. The problem occurs when I do conditional checks at the beginning of the page and I need to have the translated text in the variable to then send it to other places on the page to be displayed.

My code:

```
if ($condition_1){
    $message = $translate->__('Text 1');
}

elseif ($condition_2){
    $message = $translate->__('Text 2');
}

elseif ($condition_3){
    $message = $translate->__('Text 3');
}
```

This code echos the text in the place where this condition is put, not used as the variable $message and then echos when I need it to. Can you help me to figure out how to use the text as a variable.

If I use the text with no translator class. I can easily use it as a variable.

This is the class i use:

```
class Translator {

    private $language   = 'sl';
    private $lang       = array();

    public function __construct($language){
        $this->language = $language;
    }

    private function findString($str) {
        if (array_key_exists($str, $this->lang[$this->language])) {
            echo $this->lang[$this->language][$str];
            return;
        }
        echo $str;
    }

    private function splitStrings($str) {
        return explode('=',trim($str));
    }

    public function __($str) {  
        if (!array_key_exists($this->language, $this->lang)) {
            if (file_exists($this->language.'.txt')) {
                $strings = array_map(array($this,'splitStrings'),file($this->language.'.txt'));
                foreach ($strings as $k => $v) {
                    $this->lang[$this->language][$v[0]] = $v[1];
                }
                return $this->findString($str);
            }
            else {
                echo $str;
            }
        }
        else {
            return $this->findString($str);
        }
    }
}
```

The translated text is in the a *.txt file, looking like this:

```
text 1=text 1 translated
text 2=text 2 translated
text 3=text 3 translated
```

Comment: Well, it is pretty obvious that the methods produce output themselves. So that should not surprise you. You can either modify those methods so that the strings are returned instead of being echoed, or you use output buffering to "catch" the output.

Comment: @arkascha good catch :)

Comment: So i need to change the class.translate.php. I should replace "return" with echo?

Comment: No. In contrary. You _do_ know how to program in php, don't you?

Comment: not an expert...learning..this is the 1st time I am using classes

Comment: I have figured it out...thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the "echo" in the class. I changed the "echo" with "return" and it works like a charm!